# What is planned for Apple's fall 2013 press event?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Invitations for Apple's fall (in the northern hemisphere) 2013 press event have been sent:

- http://www.loopinsight.com/2013/09/03/apple-announces-special-event-for-september-10/

The pithy summary for this post above is: *It is widely expected that Apple will introduce a new iPhone at the event.*

I have posted a community event for [10 AM Pacific Time](http://everytimezone.com/#2013-9-10,300,1zz) that links to this discussion thread so people can share their ideas to help promote either the site or this event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, we should have a chat room event for a start, a place to hang out and share useful livestreams and other info etc, maybe open it early and let people rip with the rumours in a controlled space ;)

Comment: I'm so glad you volunteered to set up the chat room event ;-)

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/4771/apple-press-event-chat?tab=schedule

Comment: 60 min might be a bit short...

Comment: Rooms open for business before and after

Comment: There's a couple of hundred followers to the AD Twitter feed.  Can't harm to throw a tweet to the chat event out to them.  Anyone got the chops for that?

Comment: I think we need to email the team@stackexchange.com asking them to poke the people that handle the twitter account to tweet things manually.